# Using filters in apprequests dialog has no effect - Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to use the apprequests dialog to send invites to friends who do not have the app installed yet.

To show only the the friends without the app I'm using the filters param with "app_non_users". However it has no affect on the resulting dialog (i get all friends).

This is the code i'm using:

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSArray *filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"app_non_users"];

NSString *filtersString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:filters];

NSMutableDictionary* params = 
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"invites you to check out cool stuff",  @"message",
 @"Check this out", @"notification_text",
 filtersString, @"filters",
 @"Invite Friends", @"title", 
 nil];  

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

What am I missing to get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

"filter" parameter is actually not supported for mobile versions of requests dialogs; see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/:

> Note: the filters option is disabled on mobile dialogs and will not affect the set of users that appear in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a Facebook SDK bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250244258383454?browse=search_4f612ef5c4d220144914479

Update:
As of 4/19, this was marked "by design".